# if $|D_n - \frac{n!}{e}| < \frac{1}{1+n}$, why is $D_n$ nearest integer?

Tags: combinatorics

Given $D_n$ is the number of derangements (i.e. permutations s.t. $\pi(i) \neq i$ for all $i$ in $\{1,...,n\}$, where $D_n$ is defined to be: $\frac{D_n}{n!} = \sum_{0 \leq q \leq n} \frac{(-1)^q}{q!}$

Then, supposing this inequality is true:

$$
| D_n - \frac{n!}{e} | < \frac{1}{n+1}
$$

Why does this prove that $D_n$ is the nearest integer to $\frac{n!}{e}$?

So, I am not having any trouble establishing the above inequality. Rather, I am trying to understand in simple language, why the expression $\frac{1}{n+1}$ would indicate that $D_n$ was the closes integer approximation to $\frac{n!}{e}$. For example, suppose I were able to find another integer, call it $K_n$, such that,

$$
| K_n - \frac{n!}{e} | < \frac{1}{n+2}
$$

why wouldn't that establish there is a closer integer? Or how is this a contradiction?

Appreciate all the help, as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D_n$ satifies $\left|D_n-n!/e\right|<1/(n+1)$. If another integer $K_n$ satisfies $\left|K_n-n!/e\right|<\alpha$, then the triangle inequality shows that
$$
\left|D_n-K_n\right|< \frac{1}{n+1}+\alpha.
$$

In particular if $K_n\neq D_n$ is an integer closer to $n!/e$ than $D_n$, that is if $\alpha<1/(n+1)$, then, using the fact that the distance between two distinct integers is at least $1$, you obtain the contradiction
$$
1\leq \left|D_n-K_n\right|< \frac{2}{n+1}\leq1,\quad n>1.
$$

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped clear it up... I was beginning to think about the differences between $|K_n - D_n|$ but was unable to provide the inequality as you had. Thank you!

Comment: @IQ472 You're welcome. If the answer is satisfactory you can accept it formally and thus mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

$D_n$ is an integer (after all, it's the number of ...).  The distance between integers is an integer.  The only integer less than $2/(n+1)$ (if $n > 1$) is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.